# AS3 group movie clips

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I think I have a very simple question because I can't find anybody who asked it before me.
So I have mc1 and mc2. I want to do something like this:

```
(mc1,mc2).stop();
```

instead of:

```
mc1.stop();
mc2.stop();
```

What is the correct form to do this??

another example how my code looks like now:

```
function playReverse(e:Event):void {
    if (mc1.currentFrame == 1) {
        stopPlayReverse();
    } else {
        mc1.prevFrame();
    }
    if (mc2.currentFrame == 1) {
        stopPlayReverse();
    } else {
        mc2.prevFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should get you started:

```
var mcs:Array = [mc1, mc2, mc3, mc4];
for ( var i:int = 0, l:int = mcs.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    var mc:Movieclip = mcs[i] as MovieClip;
    if ( i == 0 ) mc.play(); // or watever condition you need to check...
    else mc.stop();
}
```

or you may also use for each:

```
for each ( var mc:MovieClip in mcs ) 
  mc.stop();
```